# Admob and Adsense account

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I am having a hosted account of adsense and I want to create an account for admob, My question is, is it mandatory to use the same adsense account to sign up for admob or I can use a different account for admob.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer - No,**

It's **not mandatory** to use your existing Adsense account. But if you use Google Adsense account and you would like to sign up in AdMob in your existing Adsense Account Google can allow. I recommended to use your existing Adsense account.

Comment: But if we have 2 different accounts, can we continue the same like that?

Comment: yes you can continue. your pub id is different in both account.

Comment: Hi, when i login to admob, if i try to switch to new admob account. But for that its asking me to create a new adsense account or use the existing one and link it. So we cant use admob without linking to adsense & we should only have one adsense account right?.